# How can I parse 购房贷款 in 他向银行申请了购房贷款。?

Tags: grammar, verbs

> 他向银行申请了购房贷款。

*He applied for a purchase loan from the bank.*

The above translation has been gained from DeepL.

Currently I've been struggling for understanding 购房贷款 which is used in the original sentence.

*购(to purchase)房贷(housing loan)款(fund(s)?)*

I've read 购房贷款 as above way and completely has been confused to understand the original sentence.

As I remove the both letters(购 and 款) then I have no problem.

Can you explain me how 购 and 款 work in the original sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

购房贷款 just means mortgage. Since Chinese is quite analytic, we put multiple words together to form a new meaning.

购=purchase, 房=house, 贷款=loan. Here 贷款 is formed from 贷=loan（verb） 款=fund, clearly 贷款 itself is a compound word too.

So basically it means "fund loaned for purchasing a house", which conveniently in English is just one word, mortgage.

it is just like things like 飞(flying)机(machine) = airplane or 计算（computing）机（machine）= computer. Think them as the compound word as a whole: multiple Chinese characters as one English word.

Comment: 计算机 is a calculator. correct breakdown for computer is 电 (electric) 脑 (brain)

Comment: @Nelson Both are correct. It's definitely more common to use 電腦 in oral but 計算機 is a correct term as well, though everyone will know you're mainland Chinese if you say that in Hong Kong :)

Comment: @GarethMa Really? When I use 计算机 or 計算機 on Taobao, nothing related to computers come up. I also never seen anything like a 计算机维修 (repair) on the street.

Comment: @Nelson 计算器 is calculator, 电脑 and 计算机 both means computer. 计算机 is just more for formal, for example, if you are referring to computer science, you will say 计算机科学 instead of 电脑科学.

Answer (score 2):

**购房贷款** is a noun, (or noun phrase), in the sentence 申请了购房贷款, used as the objective of the verb 申请了.

购房贷款 = 购房**的**贷款, with the word **的** omitted. 购房的 is an adjective modifying the noun 贷款. In Chinese, **noun + 的 = adjective**, such as 购房的.

**购房** and **贷款** are both nouns in the form of **verb + objective (VO)**.

**房贷** is a noun that has the same meaning as 购房贷款. 房贷 is in the form of **noun + noun**. The first noun **房** is used as an adjective, therefore 房贷 is a word of **adj + n**. 房 = 用于购买房子的.

The formation of **adj + n** (or **n + n**) is a very useful method in constructing words in Chinese, such as 书房，图书馆，商店，火车.

Answer (score 1):

房贷 is the abbreviation of the official term 购**房贷**款 or **房**屋**贷**款, similar to "housing loan" for "house purchase loan" and often addressed as "mortgage".